# Subversion and project management web based super tool. Like Team Foundation Server but not TFS

Tags: version-control, project-management

We're currently looking at an IT upgrade and I'm after recommendations for a tool which can do some or all of the following.

- SVN management (authz, web viewer, commit log, diff)
- Create template projects (1 click e.g. create me a microsite with this name in svn and give these people access)
- Reporting on code churn, time spent on tasks on a per project basis
- User story management

Basically like Team Foundation Server but that integrates with SVN properly (reason for this - we have a wide range of skill sets and not everyone can use a TFS client). Is there a combination of Trac plugins + something that can create trac instances (a la Dreamhost's admin panel) that can acheive this.

On a side note, does anyone have any experience of version controlling designery type files - e.g. PSDs, Illustrator files.

Any advice at all appreciated.

Cheers,
Rob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've found Assembla (http://www.assembla.com/). Which seems to do everything we need in a hosted solution.

Answer (score 3):

For project management i would recommend [**FogBugz**](http://www.fogcreek.com/fogbugz/)...

I have used fogbugz for all my web application test cases... It has good version control which be very useful to graph your cases from the day of first test to the latest version....

Individual logins from admin and users would be best suited for assigning,reopening and closing cases....

FogBugz makes it simple to enter bug reports and other types of cases.

Comment: They support also Mercurial repositories via their Kiln project. So if you are not absolutely tied to SVN, this may be a good option.

Comment: I hadn't considered FogBugz despite looking at it in the past, I'll definitely put it forward for consideration.

I do like the idea of Mercurial but I'm not sure we're ready here.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [JIRA](http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/) and their [SVN plugin](https://studio.plugins.atlassian.com/wiki/display/SVN/Subversion+JIRA+plugin).
There's also support for linking changesets to issues etc, just like TFS.

Side note answer: you can version control anything, but viewing a history of exact changes, differences to local version is impossible with binary files, which a PSD possibly is.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that out.

Sidenote comment on sidenote answer: I understand you can svn anything but I was looking for a more elegant solution. This seems like it might do it but the site is a bit vague. http://pixelnovel.com/

Answer (score 1):

[GForge](http://gforge.org/gf/) can support requirements 1, 2 and 4. As for project churn reporting, if you're using svn, you can use the PanBI [Subversion analysis module](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/panbi/index.php?title=Subversion) (screencast available [here](http://panbi.sourceforge.net/systems/subversion/olap.html)).

Comment: Hadn't seen these, I will check these out.